# Asymptotic approximation regarding the Gamma function $\Gamma$.

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, special-functions, gamma-function

On the [wikipedia page for Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Properties) I saw an interesting formula
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\Gamma(n+\alpha)}{\Gamma(n)n^\alpha} = 1
$$
for all $\alpha\in\Bbb C$. I couldn't find the source of this and searching here in MSE didn't provide the result I want.

> Could anyone show me how this formula is derived?

I'm very inexperienced with properties/identities of $\Gamma$ so forgive me if this question is trivial.

Comment: Use Stirlings Approximation. It's probably on that Wikipedia page.

Comment: So Stirlings approximation also works in complex case? Thank you, I didn't know that before.

Comment: This follows from [Gautschi's Inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/103028), which can be proven using the log-convexity of the Gamma function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most usual derivation of this would involve the Stirling-Laplace asymptotic for $\Gamma(s)$. I'm mildly surprised that this wasn't explicitly worked out in Wiki, or some other easily accessible places on-line.

In fact, a much simpler approach obtains (a stronger version of) this asymptotic via "Watson's Lemma", which is itself easy to completely prove from simple things, going back over 100 years. In various places in the literature, the lemma is in fact called "the oft-reproven Watson's lemma". :)

The case you mention is a simple corollary of the very first example I wrote out in some notes on asymptotic expansions: http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/mfms/notes_2013-14/02d_asymptotics_of_integrals.pdf

Comment: Thank you for you answer. By the way, your link doesn't work for me for some reason.

Comment: Oop, let me try to repair the link...

Comment: I think it works now... :)

Comment: Now it also works perfectly for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> Stirling Asymptotic:
>   $\ds{N! \sim \root{2\pi}\, N^{N + 1/2}\expo{-N}}$ as
>   $\ds{\verts{N} \to \infty}$.

\begin{align}
\left.\lim_{n \to \infty}{\Gamma\pars{n + \alpha} \over \Gamma\pars{n}n^{\alpha}}\,\right\vert_{\ \alpha\ \in\ \mathbb{C}}
& =
\lim_{n \to \infty}{\pars{n + \alpha - 1}! \over
\pars{n - 1}!\, n^{\alpha}}
\\[5mm] & =
\lim_{n \to \infty}{\root{2\pi}\pars{n + \alpha - 1}^{n + \alpha - 1/2}\expo{-\pars{n + \alpha - 1}} \over
\bracks{\root{2\pi}\pars{n - 1}^{n - 1/2}\expo{-\pars{n - 1}}}\, n^{\alpha}}
\\[5mm] & =
\lim_{n \to \infty}{n^{n + \alpha - 1/2}\,
\bracks{1 + \pars{\alpha - 1}/n}^{n + \alpha - 1/2}\,\expo{-\alpha} \over
\bracks{n^{n - 1/2}\pars{1 - 1/n}^{n - 1/2}}\, n^{\alpha}}
\\[5mm] & =
\expo{-\alpha}\lim_{n \to \infty}
{\bracks{1 + \pars{\alpha - 1}/n}^{n} \over \pars{1 - 1/n}^{n}}
\\[5mm] & =
\expo{-\alpha}\,{\expo{\alpha - 1} \over \expo{-1}} = \bbx{1}
\end{align}

Answer (score 4):

**Real $\boldsymbol{\alpha}$**

The log-convexity of the Gamma function is shown in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/101007).

Suppose that $0\le\alpha\le k\in\mathbb{Z}$, then using the recurrence relation for $\Gamma$,
$$
\begin{align}
\Gamma(n+\alpha)
&\le\Gamma(n)^{1-\alpha/k}\,\Gamma(n+k)^{\alpha/k}\\
&\le\Gamma(n)^{1-\alpha/k}\left(\Gamma(n)\,(n+k-1)^k\right)^{\alpha/k}\\
&=\Gamma(n)\,(n+k-1)^\alpha\tag1
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
\Gamma(n)
&\le\Gamma(n+\alpha-k)^{\alpha/k}\Gamma(n+\alpha)^{1-\alpha/k}\\[6pt]
&\le\left(\frac{\Gamma(n+\alpha)}{(n+\alpha-k)^k}\right)^{\alpha/k}\Gamma(n+\alpha)^{1-\alpha/k}\\
&=\frac{\Gamma(n+\alpha)}{(n+\alpha-k)^\alpha}\tag2
\end{align}
$$
Then we have
$$
\left(\frac{n+\alpha-k}{n}\right)^\alpha
\le\frac{\Gamma(n+\alpha)}{\Gamma(n)\,n^\alpha}
\le\left(\frac{n+k-1}{n}\right)^\alpha\tag3
$$
and by the Squeeze Theorem, for $\alpha\ge0$,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\Gamma(n+\alpha)}{\Gamma(n)\,n^\alpha}=1\tag4
$$
Furthermore,
$$
\begin{align}
\Gamma(n)
&\le\Gamma(n-\alpha)^{1-\alpha/k}\Gamma(n-\alpha+k)^{\alpha/k}\\
&\le\Gamma(n-\alpha)^{1-\alpha/k}\left(\Gamma(n-\alpha)(n-\alpha+k-1)^k\right)^{\alpha/k}\\
&=\Gamma(n-\alpha)(n-\alpha+k-1)^\alpha\tag5
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
\Gamma(n-\alpha)
&\le\Gamma(n)^{1-\alpha/k}\Gamma(n-k)^{\alpha/k}\\
&\le\Gamma(n)^{1-\alpha/k}\left(\frac{\Gamma(n)}{(n-k)^k}\right)^{\alpha/k}\\
&=\frac{\Gamma(n)}{(n-k)^\alpha}\tag6
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\left(\frac{n-\alpha+k-1}{n}\right)^{-\alpha}
\le\frac{\Gamma(n-\alpha)}{\Gamma(n)\,n^{-\alpha}}
\le\left(\frac{n-k}{n}\right)^{-\alpha}\tag7
$$
and by the Squeeze Theorem, for $\alpha\ge0$,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\Gamma(n-\alpha)}{\Gamma(n)\,n^{-\alpha}}=1\tag8
$$

---

**Complex $\boldsymbol{\alpha}$**

Unfortunately, I have not found a way to make the log-convexity argument that works for $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ work for $\alpha\in \mathbb{C}$. About the best I can see, is to use [Stirling's Approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation).
$$
\Gamma(n)\sim\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}n}\frac{n^n}{e^n}\tag9
$$
Applying $(9)$ to $\Gamma(n+\alpha)$ and $\Gamma(n)$, we get
$$
\frac{\Gamma(n+\alpha)}{\Gamma(n)\,n^\alpha}\sim\sqrt{\frac{n}{n+\alpha}}\frac{\left(1+\frac\alpha{n}\right)^{n+\alpha}}{e^\alpha}\tag{10}
$$
which yields
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\Gamma(n+\alpha)}{\Gamma(n)\,n^\alpha}=1\tag{11}
$$

Comment: Fyi, the Bohr-Mollerup Wikipedia page proves the real case as a direct corollary.

Comment: @adfriedman: that is not surprising since both are using the log-convexity of $\Gamma$.

Answer (score 2):

As said, Stirling approximation is the key.

Considering
$$y=\frac{\Gamma(n+a)}{\Gamma(n)\,n^a}\implies \log(y)=\log (\Gamma (a+n))-\log (\Gamma (n))-a \log(n)$$  use Stirling approximation
$$\log (\Gamma (p))=p (\log (p)-1)+\frac{1}{2} \left(\log (2 \pi
   )-\log \left({p}\right)\right)+\frac{1}{12 p}-\frac{1}{360 p^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^5}\right)$$ Just apply it and continue with Taylor series to get
$$\log(y)=\frac{(a-1) a}{2 n}-\frac{(a-1) a (2 a-1)}{12 n^2}+\frac{(a-1)^2 a^2}{12
   n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$ Continue with Taylor
$$y=e^{\log(y)}=1+\frac{(a-1) a}{2 n}+\frac{(a-2) (a-1) a (3 a-1)}{24 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$

Using it for $n=100$ and $a=5+7i$ the "exact value" would be $(0.798463+ 0.143902 \,i)$ while the above approximation would give $\frac{31947}{40000}+\frac{1057 }{7500}i\approx (0.798675 +0.140933 i)$.