# what's the name of this relation?[repeated]

Tags: functional-analysis, special-functions

$\Gamma(n+a) \sim n^{a-1} n!$ this relation is useful to get the acceleration of a function that can be written or expressed using Gamma function. I want to know its name and the proof if possible.
what I understand that it is related to Gautschi inequality, Stirling relation and strict log-convexity of Gamma function. But still can't get its name. One of the answers gives clear proof to me.

I find the answer under this question [Asymptotic approximation regarding the Gamma function $\Gamma$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3076357/asymptotic-approximation-regarding-the-gamma-function-gamma/3076639#3076639)

Comment: See this similar question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3076357/asymptotic-approximation-regarding-the-gamma-function-gamma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can demonstrate it with the Euler formula which gives Gamma as a limit of a product:

$\Gamma(z) = \lim_{n \to {+\infty}} \frac{n! \; n^z}{z \; (z+1)\cdots(z+n)}$

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}^*$. Considering $\Gamma(a+n+1)$, we have (by recurrence)

$\Gamma(a+n+1)=\Gamma(a).\prod_{k=0}^{n} (a+k)$

Thus

$\frac{\Gamma(a+n+1)}{n! n^a}=\Gamma(a).\frac{\prod_{k=0}^{n} (a+k)}{n! n^a}$

We recognize the inverse of the previous quotient

So $\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} \frac{\Gamma(a+n+1)}{n! n^a}=1$

However $\Gamma(a+n+1)=(a+n)\Gamma(a+n)$

Hence $\frac{\Gamma(a+n)}{n! n^{a-1}}=\frac{\Gamma(a+n+1)}{n! n^a}\frac{n}{n+a}$

As $\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} \frac{n}{n+a}=1$

$\boxed{\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} \frac{\Gamma(a+n)}{n! n^{a-1}}=1}$

Comment: from the last Hence to Finally there is a gap of understanding.

Comment: It is a limit of a product.

Comment: what's $N*$?. Does it mean that n is non-zero?

Comment: excuse me, what do we call this relation?

Comment: N* is the set of positive integers.

Answer (score 0):

Try to see this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation. I think your answer is here

Comment: i can't find it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Consider
$$y=\Gamma(n+a)\implies \log(y)=\log (\Gamma (n+a))$$ Suppose that $a\ll n$ and use expansion to get
$$\log(y)=\log (\Gamma (n))+a \psi (n)+O\left(a^2\right)$$ Now, for large $n$
$$\psi (n)=\log \left({n}\right)-\frac{1}{2
   n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$
$$\log(y)\sim\log (\Gamma (n))+a\log \left({n}\right)=\log \left(n^a \Gamma (n)\right)\implies y \sim n^a \Gamma (n)=n^{a-1}\Gamma(n+1)=n^{a-1}\,n!$$

Comment: i need details.

Answer (score 0):

For real $x$ and $0\lt s\lt1$, the inequality
$$
x^{1-s}<\frac{\Gamma(x+1)}{\Gamma(x+s)}<(x+1)^{1-s}\tag1
$$
is called [Gautschi's Inequality](https://dlmf.nist.gov/5.6#i) and a proof is given in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/103028).

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3076639), similar methods (the log-convexity of $\Gamma$) are used to prove two extension for $0\le\alpha\le k$
$$
\left(\frac{n+\alpha-k}{n}\right)^\alpha
\le\frac{\Gamma(n+\alpha)}{\Gamma(n)\,n^\alpha}
\le\left(\frac{n+k-1}{n}\right)^\alpha\tag2
$$
and
$$
\left(\frac{n-k}{n}\right)^{-\alpha}
\ge\frac{\Gamma(n-\alpha)}{\Gamma(n)\,n^{-\alpha}}
\ge\left(\frac{n-\alpha+k-1}{n}\right)^{-\alpha}\tag3
$$
$(2)$ or $(3)$ and the [Squeeze Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) justify the limit in the question.

The similarity of $(2)$ and $(3)$ to Gautschi seems to make citing Gautschi's Inequality a good thing to do.

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3076639) also shows how to get the limit in this question for complex arguments (since $\Gamma(n+1)=n!$).

Comment: by taking the limit of both upper and lower bound we get 1. so the limit of the middle will be equal to one. hence what I wanted. if this is it, then I am super grateful.

Comment: @TCHassnaTaha: yes, the limits of the bounds is $1$, so the limit of the bounded term is $1$.

Comment: ok, put in the middle the Gamma of $n+a$ not $n-\alpha$ what to do about that?

Comment: Look at the extensions given in $(3)$ and $(5)$ of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3076639).

Comment: I have modified my answer to include the references mentioned in my last comment.