# Compute the following product limit

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, gamma-function

From another problem, I got stuck trying to solve this limit: $$\lim_{k\to +\infty}\prod_{v=k+1}^{2k}\left(1-\frac1{va}\right)$$
where $a>1$ is a positive integer. I tried to take $\log$ on both sides and expanded each term in series, but it doesn't look easier. The result turns out to be $2^{-1/a}$, according to my book. What's the trick behind this?
One can rewrite this following the hint in the comments as $$\lim_{k\to +\infty}\frac{(\frac{a-1}a+k)(\frac{a-1}a+k+1)\cdots(\frac{a-1}a+2k-1)}{(k+1)(k+2)\cdots(2k)}.$$ What is this value?

Comment: Mathematica gives $$\prod _{v=1}^{m} \left(1-\frac{1}{a v}\right)=\frac{\left(\frac{a-1}{a}\right)_{m}}{m!},$$ where $(b)_m=b(b+1)\cdots(b+m-1)$ is the Pochhammer symbol. The result follows as a straightforward limit calculation

Comment: so you are saying that one can find a closed form?

Comment: wow it was so simple :)

Comment: so I checked Mathematica computation and it's correct, however it is just a rewriting, so I don't understand your point when you say that it follows as a "straightforward" computation; perhaps I'm missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not bad with Taylor series
$$P_k=\prod_{v=k+1}^{2k}\left(1-\frac1{va}\right)\implies \log(P_k)=\sum_{v=k+1}^{2k}\log\left(1-\frac1{va}\right)$$
$$\log\left(1-\frac1{va}\right)=-\frac{1}{a v}-\frac{1}{2 a^2 v^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{v^3}\right)$$
$$\log(P_k)=\sum_{v=k+1}^{2k}\log\left(1-\frac1{va}\right)=\frac{2 a( H_k- H_{2 k})-\psi ^{(1)}(k+1)+\psi ^{(1)}(2 k+1)}{2 a^2}$$ Now, using asymptotics
$$\log(P_k)=-\frac{\log (2)}{a}+\frac{a-1}{4 a^2 k}+\frac{3-a}{16 a^2
   k^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^3}\right)$$
$$P_k=e^{\log(P_k)}=2^{-1/a}\left(1+\frac{a-1}{4 a^2 k}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right) \right)$$

Comment: What is $\psi ^{(1)}$?

Comment: @Dude. The digamma function

Comment: I was wondering if a first order approximation is sufficient. Is it possible to deduce this taking into account that the reminder of the series $\sum 1/n^2$ goes to zero?

Comment: @Dude. Yes, it is OK to do it if you just want the limit.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with
$$
\prod _{v=1}^{m} 1-\frac{1}{va} = \frac{\left(\frac{a-1}{a}\right)_m}{m!}
$$ Then the limit you seek is
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty}  \frac{\left(\frac{a-1}{a}\right)_{2k}}{(2k)!}\cdot \frac{k!}{\left(\frac{a-1}{a}\right)_k}
$$Let's turn Pochhammer symbols and factorial into gamma functions using $(b)_m = \Gamma(b+m)/\Gamma(m)$, $m!=\Gamma(m+1)$:
$$=
\lim_{k\to\infty}  \frac{\Gamma\left(2k+\frac{a-1}{a}\right)}{\Gamma(2k+1) \Gamma\left(\frac{a-1}{a}\right)}\cdot \frac{\Gamma(k+1)\Gamma\left(\frac{a-1}{a}\right)}{\Gamma\left(k+\frac{a-1}{a}\right)}
$$
$$=
\lim_{k\to\infty}  \frac{\Gamma\left(2k+1-\frac{1}{a}\right)}{\Gamma(2k+1) }\cdot \frac{\Gamma(k+1)}{\Gamma\left(k+1-\frac{1}{a}\right)}
$$Now we use the [handy asymptotic](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.11.E12)
$$
\lim_{z\to\infty}\frac{\Gamma(z+\alpha)}{\Gamma(z+\beta)}z^{\beta-\alpha}=1;
$$matching arguments, we have
$$=
\color{green}{2^{-1/a}} \lim_{k\to\infty}  \frac{\Gamma\left(2k+1-\frac{1}{a}\right)\color{red}{(2k)^{1/a}}}{\Gamma(2k+1) }\cdot \frac{\Gamma(k+1)}{\Gamma\left(k+1-\frac{1}{a}\right)\color{blue}{k^{1/a}}}
$$
$$
=\color{green}{2^{-1/a}}  \cdot \color{red}{1}\cdot \color{blue}{1} = 2^{-1/a}
$$

---

The starting point
$$
\prod _{v=1}^{m} 1-\frac{1}{va} = \frac{\left(\frac{a-1}{a}\right)_m}{m!}
$$ can be shown by induction on $m$.

Comment: Where do I find a proof for that asymptotic?

Comment: I don't really appreciate the Gamma approach as you maybe do, perhaps because it is far above my actual knowledge. Nonetheless thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Dude no worries. I found a very good link on this question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3076389

Comment: By the way, I think there might be another proof. This problem is reminiscent of the well-known (hate to keep using this phrase) result $$\lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_{j=k+1}^{2k} \frac{1}{j}=\log(2);$$I'd be interested to know if there's an analogous way to do this problem

Comment: Thank you for the link! I will think about this problem again and see if I come up with something.

Comment: So actually I tried to elaborate your last suspicion and not surprisingly the proof comes out. It suffices to take the logs as I said in the post, and use a first order approximation for $\ln(1+x)$. One applies your last well known limit and obtains the result. I will accept your answer anyway. Very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\lim_{k \to \infty}\prod_{v = k + 1}^{2k}
\pars{1 - {1 \over va}}} =
\lim_{k \to \infty}\prod_{v = k + 1}^{2k}\pars{v - 1/a \over v} =
\lim_{k \to \infty}{\pars{k + 1 - 1/a}^{\,\overline{k}} \over
\pars{k + 1}^{\,\overline{k}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{k \to \infty}{\Gamma\pars{2k + 1 - 1/a}/\Gamma\pars{k + 1 - 1/a}
\over
\Gamma\pars{2k +1}/\Gamma\pars{k + 1}} =
\lim_{k \to \infty}{\pars{2k - 1/a}! \over \pars{k - 1/a}!}
{k!  \over \pars{2k}!}
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{k \to \infty}{\root{2\pi}\pars{2k - 1/a}^{2k + 1/2 - 1/a}
\,\expo{-2k + 1/a} \over
\root{2\pi}\pars{k - 1/a}^{k + 1/2 - 1/a}\,\expo{-k + 1/a}}\,
{\root{2\pi}k^{k + 1/2}\,\expo{-k} \over
\root{2\pi}\pars{2k}^{2k + 1/2}\,\expo{-2k}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{k \to \infty}{\pars{2k}^{2k + 1/2 - 1/a}\,
\bracks{1 - \pars{1/a}/\pars{2k}}^{\, 2k} \over
k^{k + 1/2 - 1/a}\,\bracks{1 - \pars{1/a}/k}^{\, k}}\,
{k^{k + 1/2} \over \pars{2k}^{2k + 1/2}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{k \to \infty}
{\pars{2k}^{-1/a}\expo{-1/a}k^{1/a} \over
\expo{-1/a}} = \bbx{\large{1 \over 2^{1/a}}}
\end{align}

Comment: Interesting to see you've posted alternate solutions on several questions I've answered. I've enjoyed comparing your approaches to mine.

Comment: @Integrand After my MacBook Pro worked fine again ( I was away for several months ) , I decided to visit the time line of some interesting users. That was my way to find interesting questions. Nice to see you again. Thanks.

Comment: Glad you're back too.